# Flutter show y axis values as string

Tags: flutter, dart, syncfusion-chart, sfcartesianchart

I have a simple graph in which I have x-axis as string and y-axis as int but my values are too long 10000 I need to show it as 10k

My code

```
     Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25,
          child: SfCartesianChart(
              enableAxisAnimation: true,
              primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(
                  majorGridLines: MajorGridLines(width: 0),
                  //Hide the axis line of x-axis
                  axisLine: AxisLine(width: 0),
                  interval: 1),
              primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(
                minimum: 0, maximum: highSale,
                interval: highSale < 200 ? 100 : 2000,
                majorGridLines: MajorGridLines(width: 0),
                //Hide the axis line of x-axis
                axisLine: AxisLine(width: 0),
              ),
              tooltipBehavior: _tooltip,
              plotAreaBorderWidth: 0,
              legend: Legend(isVisible: false),
              series: <ChartSeries<_ChartData, String>>[
                ColumnSeries<_ChartData, String>(
                    dataSource: weekly
                        ? data
                        : yearly
                            ? dataMonth
                            : monthly
                                ? dataDaily
                                : daily
                                    ? dataDaily
                                    : [],
                    xValueMapper: (_ChartData data, _) => data.x,
                    yValueMapper: (_ChartData data, _) => data.y,
                    
                    pointColorMapper: (_ChartData data, _) => data.color,
                    name: 'Week',
                    color: weekly ? kPrimaryColor : Colors.red)
              ]),
        ),
```

In the image you can see it's showing 36000 I need to show it as 36k I try to convert it to k value but the issue is on yValueMapper it's showing string isn't allowed. So what I was thinking is maybe there is some value to show mapper? like graph will work on value mapper and text will be different.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The above answer is correct but you need to format the primary axis

Like this

```
  primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(
    numberFormat: NumberFormat.compact(),
  )
```

Comment: [numberFormat](https://github.com/syncfusion/flutter-widgets/blob/ac9ea48cb13bfcb377f4bfccd577d1229d8bd62c/packages/syncfusion_flutter_charts/lib/src/chart/axis/numeric_axis.dart#L41)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `NumberFormat` class from `intl` package

Like so:

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  final number = NumberFormat.compact().format(10000);

  print(number); // 10k
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I need to show this on the graph.

Comment: are you using some third party package? maybe you'll have to edit it

Comment: I belive he's using this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_charts)